# GCC Inline Assembly to IAR Inline Assembly

Tags: assembly, embedded, inline-assembly, iar

I am attempting to use [BeRTOS](http://bertos.org) for a Texas Instruments Stellaris Cortex-M3. My work environment is IAR. There were a lot of minor changes to accommodate IAR and the specific uC that I am using but I've got one that I can't seem to solve... and frankly it's a bit over my head.

This bit of code:

```
1    void NAKED lm3s_busyWait(unsigned long iterations)
2    {
3       register uint32_t __n __asm("r0") = iterations;
4
5       __asm volatile (
6           "1: subs r0, #1\n\t"
7           "bne 1b\n\t"
8           "bx lr\n\t"
9           : : "r"(__n) : "memory", "cc");
10
11    }
```

... is generating a few errors and warnings.

> Error: expected a ";"   ----->  Line 3
>
> Error: expected a "("   ----->  Line 5
>
> Error: expected a ")"   ----->  Line 9
>
> Warning: variable "__n" was declared but never referenced   ----->  Line 3

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider looking at this.  It notes specifically that it's not for Cortex cores, but it does provide into like "don't reference a specific register"...  http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=86655

Comment: Later versions of the IAR tools support GCC-style inline assembly. I don't think there is a way to explicitly use r0, but the syntax allow you let the compiler pick a register for you. See the IAR compiler manual for details.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm pretty sure that IAR's compiler doesn't support inline assembly; at least I've always used an actual separate assembly language source file whenever I've need to do things at that level when using IAR's tools.</strike>

The code you posted looks like it's more or less equivalent to the following C code:

```
void lm3s_busyWait( unsigned long iterations)
{
    register volatile unsigned long n = iterations;

    while (--n) {
        /* do nothing */
    }
}
```

You might be able to use that in place of your version, but it'll be somewhat slower. Whether that matters or not depends on what you're using it for. Compilers generally won't place a `volatile` in a register, so intead of decrementing a register, the function would likely be hitting a memory location.

The following is a small ARM assembly function that you can put into a file named `lm3s_busyWait.s` and add it to your IAR project.  It should be exactly equivalent to the version you have using GCC's inline assembly:

```
    /* C prototype:
     *
     *  void lm3s_busyWait( unsigned long iterations);
     *
     */
    PUBLIC  lm3s_busyWait

    SECTION .text:CODE:NOROOT(4)
    THUMB

lm3s_busyWait:
    subs r0, #1
    bne lm3s_busyWait
    bx lr

    end
```

Comment: The IAR compiler has supported a simple form of inline assembler for ages, later versions support gcc-style inline assembler, allowing the code to specify input and output registers.

Comment: @Lindydancer: thanks for the pointer - I had looked for some information on inline assembly in IAR (EWARM 6.1) before posting my answer, and still missed the info (it's in "Part 1: Using the build tools"/"Assembler language interface", and the info is pretty skimpy). I still see no info on gcc-style inline assembly, but I only have 6.1 and the current version is up to 6.4.